# Get only the objects whom particular property is fulfilled in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having this array of objects:

```
myArray = [
    {name: "aaa", type: "1"},
    {name: "bbb", type: "2"},
    {name: "aaa", type: "3"},
    {name: "ddd", type: "1"},
    {name: "xxx", type: "3"},
    {name: "bbbb", type: "1"},
];
```

All this data is shown in a table. I'm implementing a drop-down selector which contains the list of `type`.

I want to be able to show in the table only the objects respecting the condition.

For example, if there is selected `1` from the selector it should show in the table this data:

```
{name: "aaa", type: "1"},
{name: "ddd", type: "1"},
{name: "bbbb", type: "1"},
```

For now, I have written function but it's not working.

```
updateTable(type) {
    const newArray = [];
    if (type === 1) {
        for (let i =0; i< myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i].type === 1) {
                newArray.push({myArray[i]});
            }
        }
    }
    if (type === 2) {
        for (let i =0; i< myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i].type === 2) {
                newArray.push({myArray[i]});
            }
        }
    }
    if (type === 3) {
        for (let i =0; i< myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i].type === 3) {
                newArray.push({myArray[i]});
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;

}
```

I tried to do it by creating a new array which isn't the best way. Is there a solution without creating a new array?

Comment: `I tried to do it by creating a new array which isn't the best way`   Why would that not be the best way?,.

Comment: please add the html part as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collapse not wanted rows by checking the option of the select element.

```js
var array = [{ name: "aaa", type: "1" }, { name: "bbb", type: "2" }, { name: "aaa", type: "3" }, { name: "ddd", type: "1" }, { name: "xxx", type: "3" }, { name: "bbbb", type: "1" }],
    types = new Set;

array.forEach((o, i) => {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.id = 'row' + i;
    ['name', 'type'].forEach(k => {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = o[k];
        tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    document.getElementById('tableData').appendChild(tr);
    types.add(o.type);
});

Array.from(types).sort((a, b) => a - b).forEach(t => {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = t;
    option.innerHTML = t;
    document.getElementById('selectType').appendChild(option);
});

function update(element) {
    var option = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    array.forEach((o, i) => {
        document.getElementById('row' + i).style.visibility = !option || option === o.type
            ? 'visible'
            : 'collapse';
    });
}
```

```html
<select id="selectType" onchange="update(this)">
    <option value="">all</option>
</select>
<table id="tableData">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>type</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code was not working because of `type === 1`. Because (===) check value and type. And in array type is a string but in the function argument it is a number. Hence, it is never equated to true.

Secondly, update your function to following

```
updateTable(type) {
   return myArray.filter(function(item){
      return item.type == type;
   });
}
```

Comment: `Is there a solution without creating a new array?`

Comment: >I tried to do it by creating a new array which isn't the best way . because he doesnt know that creating a new array is the better and correct way

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

this will reduce an object with keys of all your types with an array containing those types

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    name: "aaa",
    type: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "bbb",
    type: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "aaa",
    type: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "ddd",
    type: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "xxx",
    type: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "bbbb",
    type: "1"
  },
];

function filterIntoTypes() {
  return myArray.reduce((p, c) => {
    if (!p[c.type]) {
      p[c.type] = []
    }
    p[c.type] = [...p[c.type], c]
    return p;
  }, {})
}

const types = filterIntoTypes()


console.log(types['1'])
console.log(types['2'])
console.log(types['3'])
```

Comment: this is into an object with all the types in a property of the name

Comment: instead of just firing filter each time he can just change the property

Answer (score 0):

The filter method can be used for this purpose:

```
updateTable(type) {
    return myArray.filter(elem => elem.type == type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a solution without creating a new array?

Yes, but often creating a new array is usually better,.  Objects inside arrays are only references so it's not like it a memory / performance issue.  btw. Array.map, Array.filter create new arrays.

But if you still want to update the original array, you can use splice to delete the ones you don't want.  Trick here though is to go through the array backwards as the length changes as going forward could skip required indexes.

```js
var myArray = [
    {name: "aaa", type: "1"},
    {name: "bbb", type: "2"},
    {name: "aaa", type: "3"},
    {name: "ddd", type: "1"},
    {name: "xxx", type: "3"},
    {name: "bbbb", type: "1"}
];

function updateTable(type) {
  for (var l = myArray.length - 1; l >= 0; l --) {
    if (myArray[l].type !== type) {
      myArray.splice(l, 1);
    }
  }
}

updateTable("1");
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

## ES6

> Is there a solution without creating a new array

Yes for this, you could use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) this `return` filtered data based on condition passed.

**DEMO**

```js
const myArray = [
    {name: "aaa", type: "1"},
    {name: "bbb", type: "2"},
    {name: "aaa", type: "3"},
    {name: "ddd", type: "1"},
    {name: "xxx", type: "3"},
    {name: "bbbb", type: "1"}
];

function updateTable(value) {
 return myArray.filter(({type})=>type==value);
}


console.log(updateTable("1"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```